# How to silently reauthenticate microsoft token using firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

How to silently reauthenticate microsoft token using firebase.
`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentuser.getIdToken()`  does not work
I need the microsoft token, I'm using FirebaseOAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication only uses the OAuth token from the federated provider (Microsoft here) during the initial sign in of the user. After that, refreshing the ID token is an internal operation for Firebase Authentication that doesn't require it to reach out to Microsoft anymore.

So if you want to capture the OAuth token from Microsoft, you'll have to do so during the initial sign in from the `OAuthCredential` that you get back from the Microsoft auth provider.